# How to avoid Modelica Large Output File

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have an external function that I require to call at most twice during the simulation. It has a large output of size `Real[n][m][k]` where n, m, and ks product is a relatively large integer. I call the function inside a when statement. The issue I have is that the output of the function is copied over and over in .mat file for each iteration and causes it to be really large even though I use the output infrequently. I wonder if there is a way to store the output only once and avoid storing the copies of the output in the results file for each time step.

P.s. If that is not possible I might try to store the results of the function in another file, but need to use them in the simulation. So as an alternative is there also a way to make the simulation ignore storing a variable in the results file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to store a subset of variables only at certain points in time.

### Select variables

What can be done is using `HideResult` to avoid storing them in the result file. They can still be used in the simulation though. As an example:

```
model HideRes
  Real y1 annotation(HideResult=true);
  Integer y2;
  parameter Real x1 = 1;
  parameter Real x2 = 2 annotation(HideResult=true);
equation 
  when time > 0.1 then
    y1 = sin(x1);
  elsewhen time > 0.2 then
    y1 = sin(x2);
  end when;
  y2 = 10*integer(y1);

end HideRes;
```

In the above code, `y1` and `x2` will not be shown in the result file.

#### Protect variables

As an alternative to the above (thanks Hans O. for pointing at this) it is also possible to use `protected` variables. By default, they will not be stored in the result file. Additionally, they will not be accessible from higher levels of hierarchy in the model itself. Also parameters will not show up in the parameter dialog.
Below is the same example with `protected` applied (the `parameter x2` cannot be modified from the outside).

```
model HideRes
  Integer y2;
  parameter Real x1 = 1;
  
  protected
  Real y1;
  parameter Real x2 = 2;
  
equation 
  when time > 0.1 then
    y1 = sin(x1);
  elsewhen time > 0.2 then
    y1 = sin(x2);
  end when;
  y2 = 10*integer(y1);

end HideRes;
```

#### Chose timing

Some simulators also offer the possibility to store only at defined events. For Dymola, this would e.g. be:

```
when x > 0 then
  Dymola.Simulation.TriggerResultSnapshot();
end when;
```

Note: it stores all variables, not just a subset.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer is one of the things I was looking for. I wonder if there is also a mechanism to store the variables and parameters only once in modelica result file as well.

Comment: For parameters this is done e.g. by Dymola (it will not be shown by the GUI though). This is possible as they are not allowed to change during simulation. As far as I know, all variables are stored at every output point.

Comment: A minor nitpick: parameters are in Dymola not stored _once, but _twice_ - with times corresponding to start and stop-time - making the plot-handling more uniform. Time-varying variables are stored at every output point.
And in addition to HideResult you can also make variables protected (they are as default not stored) or use Variable Selections.

Comment: @HansOlsson: Variable Selections are a Dymola-thing, but this question is about OpenModelica.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also checked the source for Openmodelica and tried to go over its iterations yesterday. I couldn't yet figure out how the results are written to a file but so far what I have found out is that values of all the variables at the current time is kept in the data structure. So I guess it might be possible to implement something like ResultSnapshot() by traversing the data structure recursively.

Comment: The comment of Hans Olsson is pretty interesting too but I guess implementing that might be a bit problematic as the time step is automatically varied in the simulation.